# Redirecting sudirectory requests to another IP in LAN

Tags: apache-2.4, redirect, rewrite

I am trying to redirect /net for myfakedomain.com to another ip xxx.xxx.xxx.120 in the LAN.

I.e., when I try to access myfakedomain.com/net it should show the contents of xxx.xxx.xxx.120

I am also redirecting http requests to https as follows

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName myfakedomain.com
    Redirect 301 / https://myfakedomain.com/

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName www.myfakedomain.com
    Redirect 301 / https://www.myfakedomain.com/

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:443>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName myfakedomain.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    RewriteEngine on

    # just in case (don't want to accidentally expose all the internal servers) !
    ProxyRequests off

    # define a log file
    LogLevel warn rewrite:trace3

    # add the tailing / if not there
    RewriteRule     ^/net$          https://myfakedomain.com/net/  [R] [L]

    # proxy the request to internal url
    RewriteRule     ^/net/*      http://xxx.xxx.xxx.120/$1 [P]

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myfakedomain.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myfakedomain.com/privkey.pem
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myfakedomain
    <Directory /var/www/html/myfakedomain/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName www.myfakedomain.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    RewriteEngine on

    # just in case (don't want to accidentally expose all the internal servers) !
    ProxyRequests off

    # define a log file
    LogLevel warn rewrite:trace3

    # add the tailing / if not there
    RewriteRule     ^/net$          https://www.myfakedomain.com/net/  [R] [L]

    # proxy the request to internal url
    RewriteRule     ^/net/*      http://xxx.xxx.xxx.120/$1 [P]

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myfakedomain.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myfakedomain.com/privkey.pem
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myfakedomain
    <Directory /var/www/html/myfakedomain/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

It is trying to load the page from xxx.xxx.xxx.120, But all the images, css, and js are trying to load from myfakedomain.com as follows

```
GET https://myfakedomain.com/themes/default/js/functions.js 404 (Not Found)
```

and hence failing to load with 404 not found.

I tried using mod_proxy_html, and below is my virtual host conf file. Still it is the same, only difference is that there is a border (outline) for all the images, which was not there earlier.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myfakedomain.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        Redirect 301 / https://myfakedomain.com/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.myfakedomain.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        Redirect 301 / https://www.myfakedomain.com/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName myfakedomain.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    <Location /net>
            ProxyHTMLLinks a href
            ProxyHTMLLinks area href
            ProxyHTMLLinks link href
            ProxyHTMLLinks img src longdesc usemap
            ProxyHTMLLinks object classid codebase data usemap
            ProxyHTMLLinks q cite
            ProxyHTMLLinks blockquote cite
            ProxyHTMLLinks ins cite
            ProxyHTMLLinks del cite
            ProxyHTMLLinks form action
            ProxyHTMLLinks input src usemap
            ProxyHTMLLinks head profile
            ProxyHTMLLinks base href
            ProxyHTMLLinks script src for

            ProxyHTMLEvents onclick ondblclick onmousedown onmouseup \
                        onmouseover onmousemove onmouseout onkeypress \
                        onkeydown onkeyup onfocus onblur onload \
                        onunload onsubmit onreset onselect onchange

            ProxyPass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.120/
            ProxyPassReverse http://xxx.xxx.xxx.120/
            ProxyHTMLEnable On
            ProxyHTMLExtended On
            SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE;
            ProxyHTMLURLMap http://xxx.xxx.xxx.120/ /net
    </Location>

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myfakedomain.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myfakedomain.com/privkey.pem
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myfakedomain

    <Directory /var/www/html/myfakedomain/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName www.myfakedomain.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    <Location /net>
            ProxyHTMLLinks a href
            ProxyHTMLLinks area href
            ProxyHTMLLinks link href
            ProxyHTMLLinks img src longdesc usemap
            ProxyHTMLLinks object classid codebase data usemap
            ProxyHTMLLinks q cite
            ProxyHTMLLinks blockquote cite
            ProxyHTMLLinks ins cite
            ProxyHTMLLinks del cite
            ProxyHTMLLinks form action
            ProxyHTMLLinks input src usemap
            ProxyHTMLLinks head profile
            ProxyHTMLLinks base href
            ProxyHTMLLinks script src for

            ProxyHTMLEvents onclick ondblclick onmousedown onmouseup \
                        onmouseover onmousemove onmouseout onkeypress \
                        onkeydown onkeyup onfocus onblur onload \
                        onunload onsubmit onreset onselect onchange

            ProxyPass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.120/
            ProxyPassReverse http://xxx.xxx.xxx.120/
            ProxyHTMLEnable On
            ProxyHTMLExtended On
            SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE;
            ProxyHTMLURLMap http://xxx.xxx.xxx.120/ /net
        </Location>

        SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myfakedomain.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myfakedomain.com/privkey.pem
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myfakedomain

        <Directory /var/www/html/myfakedomain/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen with "/themes/"  exactly. You don't have any directive affecting that path or anything.

Comment: I am trying to redirect subdirectory "/net" access for my domain myfakedomain.com. i.e when i access myfakedomain.com/net it should go to http://xxx.xxx.xxx.120/ . So now the front page loads. But the link for images are broken since it is trying to access the images, css and js from the main domain i.e myfakedomain.com/* whereas it should be in the form myfakedomain.com/net/*

Comment: To be more precise. It should have been https://myfakedomain.com/net/themes/* instead it tries to load all the related files from https://myfakedomain.com/themes/. And the link which is seen above containing themes is only one such link. But there are more directories and files which are being accessed from same path i.e. /js /images etc.

Comment: You need to fix your system at `xxx.xxx.xxx.120` so that it includes correct URLs to the resources (with the `/net` prefix). Another option is to add a rewrite rule that makes all the needed 301 redirects from `/themes/*` to `/net/themes` in the server. However, the latter option is inefficient.

Comment: Redirecting would not work, Since the ip xxx.xxx.xxx.120 is a local lan ip. And even if it had a public ip, I would not want the ip address to be displayed in the address bar.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common problem. You want to proxy something that wants to be served under '/' as if it were under some other URI path (in this case `/net/`).

If the underlying server only ever sends Location, Content-Location or URI header redirects then you can fix these with `ProxyPassReverse`, but if the underlying HTML has links to resources with either fully qualified URLs, or URI paths that starts '/' then you have only 3 real choices.

1. Change the underlying server to serve it content under the URI path you wish to use. (Definitely the best choice with applications deployed to application servers such as tomcat)
2. Use Apache v2.4's mod_proxy_html to *correct* the HTML/css/js being served by the underlying server.
3. Hack something together with mod_sed/mod_substitute to manually correct the references in the HTML.

There is a 4th option where to you can try rewrite any other URI paths that the underlying server, but this is even more messy than the ones described above and it is rarely possible if you are proxying the resources of more than one underlying service.

Comment: Actually the problem is applications on the main domain uses php7.0 and I also want to serve some applications trough subdirectory which are not yet upgraded to php7.0 they run on php5, so obviously the first choice cannot be used. And sorry for my ignorance, but I am really not that well versed in apache, could you please give more info on the 2nd and 3rd options you have provided. Or at least some links that can help.

Comment: I tried to do the way you have suggested in the 2nd option, But still it is the same, I have updated the changes to the conf file as "Update 1" above, in addition to that I have activated the modules "proxy proxy_http proxy_html and xml2enc"

Comment: Your basic setup looks OK and the method can work, and does for many people. You just need to debug it. I would start by increasing the log level for just mod_proxy_html (and maybe mod_proxy) and see what the error log says when you make a single request.